# The rank of Bittrain coin

Tags: tokens

I would like to but a bittrain coin. I have gone through the list and I cant find it ranking.

Can I buy it on this platform?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a cryptocurrency exchange, it's a website where people ask and answer questions about Ethereum.

Comment: Your picture of Abe is extremely fitting